# Load data from Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery using Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-bigquery

I want to upload data from Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery, but I can't find any Java sample  code describing how to do this. Would someone please give me some hint as how to do this?

What I actually wanna do is to transfer data from Google App Engine tables to BigQuery (and sync on a daily basis), so that I can do some analysis. I use the Google Cloud Storage Service in Google App Engine to write (new) records to files in Google Cloud Storage, and the only missing part is to append the data to tables in BigQuery (or create a new table for first time write). Admittedly I can manually upload/append the data using the BigQuery browser tool, but I would like it to be automatic, otherwise I need to manually do it everyday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any java samples for loading tables from Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery. That said, if you follow the instructions for running query jobs [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/gettingstartedwithjava#insertqueryjob), you can run a Load job instead with the folowing:

```
Job job = new Job();
JobConfiguration config = new JobConfiguration();
JobConfigurationLoad loadConfig = new JobConfigurationLoad();
config.setLoad(loadConfig);

job.setConfiguration(config);

// Set where you are importing from (i.e. the Google Cloud Storage paths).
List<String> sources = new ArrayList<String>();
sources.add("gs://bucket/csv_to_load.csv");
loadConfig.setSourceUris(sources);

// Describe the resulting table you are importing to:
TableReference tableRef = new TableReference();
tableRef.setDatasetId("myDataset");
tableRef.setTableId("myTable");
tableRef.setProjectId(projectId);
loadConfig.setDestinationTable(tableRef);

List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<TableFieldSchema>();
TableFieldSchema fieldFoo = new TableFieldSchema();
fieldFoo.setName("foo");
fieldFoo.setType("string");
TableFieldSchema fieldBar = new TableFieldSchema();
fieldBar.setName("bar");
fieldBar.setType("integer");
fields.add(fieldFoo);
fields.add(fieldBar);
TableSchema schema = new TableSchema();
schema.setFields(fields);
loadConfig.setSchema(schema);

// Also set custom delimiter or header rows to skip here....
// [not shown].

Insert insert = bigquery.jobs().insert(projectId, job);
insert.setProjectId(projectId);
JobReference jobRef =  insert.execute().getJobReference();

// ... see rest of codelab for waiting for job to complete.
```

For more information on the load configuration object, see the javadoc [here](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/apis/bigquery/v2/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/JobConfigurationLoad.html).

Comment: Thanks very much for your code. I tried it and it worked very well. In order for this snippet to be useful more people, there are a couple of minor typos in it, and it will be great if you could revise it a bit. 1. Line 3 "JobConfigurationQLoad" should be "JobConfigurationLoad"; 2. Jobs.insert() function require two parameters and the first parameter is a String (although it doesn't matter what you put in there); 3. In the last line of code, I think you mean "JobReference jobRef" instead of "jobId". Thanks again!

Comment: Code updated with the changes you've suggested. Thanks for the feedback.