# 400 Bad Request error attempting to load bigquery table from cloud store

Tags: google-bigquery

I get a 400 bad request error:

Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Bad Request",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Bad Request"
}
```

I'm not sure how to see the full request, but using Job's toPrettyString() method I get:

```
{configuration=
  {load=
    {
      createDisposition=CREATE_IF_NEEDED, 
      destinationTable={
        datasetId=vcf1, 
        projectId=x8-alien-rainfall-3, 
        tableId=NewTable
      }, 
      encoding=UTF-8,
      maxBadRecords=10, 
      schema={
        fields=[
          {name=sample_id, type=String}, 
          {name=chromosome, type=String}, 
          {name=start_pos, type=Integer}, 
          {name=end_pos, type=Integer}, 
          {name=reference, type=String}, 
          {name=observed, type=String}, 
          {name=quality, type=Float}, 
          {name=filter, type=String}, 
          {name=zygosity, type=String}, 
          {name=refGene_function, type=String}
        ]
      }, 
      skipLeadingRows=1, 
      sourceUris=[gs://vcfs/test_exome_part1.csv]
    }
  }, 
  jobReference={projectId=x8-alien-rainfall-3}
}
```

I setup my request using the instructions here: [Load data from Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671266/load-data-from-google-cloud-storage-to-bigquery-using-java) .  The actual code is shown below:

```
  public static void loadCsvAsNewTable(Bigquery bigquery,
                                Integer skipLeadingRows,
                                Integer maxBadRecords)
      throws IOException {

    String encoding = "UTF-8";
    String csvFile = "gs://vcfs/test_exome_part1.csv";
    String datasetId = "vcf1";
    String tableId = "NewTable";

    Job insertJob = new Job();
    insertJob.setJobReference(new JobReference().setProjectId(PROJECT_ID));
    JobConfiguration config = new JobConfiguration();
    JobConfigurationLoad loadConfig = new JobConfigurationLoad();
    config.setLoad(loadConfig);

    List<String> sources = new ArrayList<String>();
    sources.add(csvFile);
    loadConfig.setSourceUris(sources);

    TableReference destinationTable = new TableReference();
    destinationTable.setDatasetId(datasetId);
    destinationTable.setTableId(tableId);
    destinationTable.setProjectId(PROJECT_ID);
    loadConfig.setDestinationTable(destinationTable);
    loadConfig.setSchema(tableSchema());
    loadConfig.setCreateDisposition("CREATE_IF_NEEDED");

    if (skipLeadingRows != null) {
      loadConfig.setSkipLeadingRows(skipLeadingRows);
    }
    if (maxBadRecords != null) {
      loadConfig.setMaxBadRecords(maxBadRecords);
    }

    loadConfig.setEncoding(encoding);
    config.setLoad(loadConfig);
    insertJob.setConfiguration(config);

    System.out.println(insertJob.toPrettyString());

    Insert insert = bigquery.jobs().insert(PROJECT_ID, insertJob);
    insert.setProjectId(PROJECT_ID);

    println("Starting load job.");
    Job job = insert.execute();
    if (isJobRunning(job)) {
      Job doneJob = waitForJob(bigquery, PROJECT_ID, job.getJobReference());
      println("Done: " + doneJob.toString());
    } else {
      println("Error: " + job.toString());
    }
  }
```

I'm able to query a table using the same GoogleCredential, which uses a Service Account approach.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answered my own question. The field types specified in the schema portion of the request have to be lower case: string instead of String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field types specified in the schema portion of the request have to be lower case: string instead of String

Answer (score 1):

Exception code 400 denotes ***billingTierLimitExceeded***.

This error returns when you try to execute a high-compute query that exceeds your project's maximum billing tier.

**Troubleshooting:** Reduce the number of calculations done per input byte or enable high-compute queries to allow more calculations per byte.

You can refer here [Troubleshooting Errors](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors)