# Loading table with thousands of columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a CSV data files holding over 5000 variables (columns). Can this be loaded into a BigQuery table? If so what would be the best option as the web UI import wizard dialog "specify schema" step truncate the schema specification string.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your rows aren't too big, there shouldn't be a problem with 5000 columns.  What is too big? The BigQuery [documentation](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery) says 20MB is the max size per row when using JSON, or 1 MB with CSV.

If you have that many columns, I'd suggest using the bq.py command-line [client](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/hello_bigquery) to do the load.

Comment: Thanks, will continue to investigate. What is too long is the string that defines the schema column (5000+ colon separated name:type) as it gets truncated in the interactive BigQuery import wizard UI (in the specify schema step). I'm actually now trying to create the table and import from cloud storage using Apps Script. Any example floating around? Other option I would be comfortable with would be Java. But I'll take a peek at the suggested Python script.

Comment: If you want to use java, there is a java load example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671266/load-data-from-google-cloud-storage-to-bigquery-using-java